# QueryString parameter binding with an array

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I'm following all of the documentation I can find for binding a querystring parameter to an action parameter of type int[], but my array is always empty.

To repro: Spin up a vanilla aspnet core web application, ASP.NET Core 2.1, API template project, and modify the default ValuesController by adding the following action:

```
[HttpGet("count")]
public ActionResult<int> GetCountOfItems([FromQuery]int[] number)
{
    return number.Count();
}
```

Calling this action like so:

```
GET /values/count?number=1&number=2
```

Should return 2, but always ends up 0.

Any ideas outside of creating custom model binders?

Comment: I am using version 2.1.301. I am not able to reproduce issue so It seems that this issue is being solved.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will ship with the next patch. You can see the issue here for more detail: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712

Answer (score 1):

Until the proper patch is rolled out, you can specify the name argument for the FromQuery attribute constructor.

```
[FromQuery(Name="number")]
```

Leaving this as the answer until then